# How to put Processing.JS code onto a webpage?

Tags: javascript, processing

I need to know how to put [processing-js](https://github.com/processing-js/processing-js) onto html code, I have tried using  command but it does not work for me

Answer (score 1):

Minimal [processing-js](https://github.com/processing-js/processing-js) example:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/processing.js/1.6.6/processing.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="pjs"></canvas>

<script type="application/processing" data-processing-target="pjs">
void setup() {
    size(200, 100);
}

void draw() {
    background(127);
    stroke(0);
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    rect(10, 10, 100, 50);
}
</script>
```

---

However, I recommend using [p5.js](https://p5js.org/). `p5.js` is slightly different from [Processing](https://processing.org/) but is well [documented](https://p5js.org/reference/) and you can use Javascript directly:

```js
function setup() {
    createCanvas(200, 100);
}

function draw() {
    background(127);
    stroke(0);
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    rect(10, 10, 100, 50);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.2.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```